# VBA code that refreshes sheet Monday-Friday at an interval

Tags: excel, vba

Please I need help, I have tried lots of different options and code via VBA but nothing seems to be working. I'm new to programming. I need a VBA code that can automatically refresh my excel sheet (cell A to D) every 1 mins, Friday to Sunday, from 8 am-4 pm.

Thank you

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so we can help you. Your question will probably be closed as 'off-topic' otherwise, as this is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Try `Application.OnTime` in [VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Application.OnTime) with `ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll`